# couldn't clear exception on retrifit2 response as "JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was STRING"

Tags: android, json, retrofit2, gson

I have found many related questions but I couldn't figure out the issue in my case since I am not that much familiar with retrofit.

```
RestServiceBuilder.getApiService().getAllProductByCatId(TOKEN, Constants.KEY_ROUTE_PRODUCTS_BY_CAT_ID,
            Constants.LIST_VIEW_LIMIT, page, CATEGORY_ID).enqueue(new Callback<ProductListBaseModel>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<ProductListBaseModel> call, Response<ProductListBaseModel> response) {
            if (response.code() == 400 || response.code() == 500) {
                ErrorPojoClass errorPojoClass = ErrorUtils.parseApiError(response);
                CustomPopup.displayErrorPopup(a, errorPojoClass);

            } else {
                try {
                    if (response.body().getData().isEmpty()) {

                        pullToLoadView.setComplete();
                        isLoading = false;

                        if (page == 1) {
                            OnProductListResponse listResponse = (OnProductListResponse) a;
                            listResponse.onEmptyProductListFound(true); // produts not found
                        } else {
                        }

                    } else {
                        setupAdapterView(page, response);
                        OnProductListResponse listResponse = (OnProductListResponse) a;
                        listResponse.onEmptyProductListFound(false); // produts found
                    }
                    isSingleProduct = false;
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Log.e( "found",""+e);
                }
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(@NonNull Call<ProductListBaseModel> call, Throwable t) {
            isLoading = false;
            Log.e( "found",""+t);
        }
    });
```

Here is how I created retrofit object

```
public static <S> S createService(Class<S> serviceClass) {

    Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
            .setDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ")
            .setLenient()
            .create();

    HttpLoggingInterceptor interceptor = new HttpLoggingInterceptor();
    interceptor.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY);
    OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
            .addInterceptor(interceptor).build();


    Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .client(client)
            .baseUrl(OPENCART_BASEURL)
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson))
            .build();


    return retrofit.create(serviceClass);
}
```

This is my model class which is used to store data from the response.

```
public class ProductListBaseModel {

@SerializedName("success")
@Expose
private Integer success;
@SerializedName("error")
@Expose
private List<Object> error = null;
@SerializedName("data")
@Expose
private List<ProductListDataModel> data = null;

public Integer getSuccess() {
    return success;
}

public void setSuccess(Integer success) {
    this.success = success;
}

public List<Object> getError() {
    return error;
}

public void setError(List<Object> error) {
    this.error = error;
}

public List<ProductListDataModel> getData() {
    return data;
}

public void setData(List<ProductListDataModel> data) {
    this.data = data;
}

private String unknown_error;

public ProductListBaseModel(int statusCode, String message) {
    this.success = statusCode;
    this.unknown_error = message;
}
```

}

I have logged the flow and then got the exception as

```
com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was STRING
```

I checked the response in posman and found that its a valid Json data. I have found many questions related to this,but couldn't solve my issue.

Comment: Check the format of response that is coming from api and the format of response that you have defined in your model.

Comment: can you add the json that you get in response

Answer (score 0):

This is due to the **Model class** that you define to gets the data in String format and the data that is coming from the **API** is in OBJECT format.

Make sure that the **Model class** that you define for getting the data is been exact the same format as data that you are getting from the **API**.